# datasource connection issue in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I am having a problem that just seemed to come out of nowhere and I am getting lost.

I am using SQL Server 2012 and have been able to connect to the database using the default connection in order to use Membership Entities.

Now whenever I try to login or register I get the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

further down the error page I see:

> SQLExpress database file auto-creation error:
>
> The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance
>   using a database location within the application's App_Data directory.
>   The provider attempted to automatically create the application
>   services database because the provider determined that the database
>   does not exist. The following configuration requirements are necessary
>   to successfully check for existence of the application services
>   database and automatically create the application services database:
>
> If the application is running on either Windows 7 or Windows Server
>   2008R2, special configuration steps are necessary to enable automatic
>   creation of the provider database. Additional information is available
>   at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=160102. If the
>   application's App_Data directory does not already exist, the web
>   server account must have read and write access to the application's
>   directory. This is necessary because the web server account will
>   automatically create the App_Data directory if it does not already
>   exist. If the application's App_Data directory already exists, the web
>   server account only requires read and write access to the
>   application's App_Data directory. This is necessary because the web
>   server account will attempt to verify that the Sql Server Express
>   database already exists within the application's App_Data directory.
>   Revoking read access on the App_Data directory from the web server
>   account will prevent the provider from correctly determining if the
>   Sql Server Express database already exists. This will cause an error
>   when the provider attempts to create a duplicate of an already
>   existing database. Write access is required because the web server
>   account's credentials are used when creating the new database. Sql
>   Server Express must be installed on the machine. The process identity
>   for the web server account must have a local user profile. See the
>   readme document for details on how to create a local user profile for
>   both machine and domain accounts.

I'm not running sqlexpress and nowhere in my webconfig does it point to sqlexpress.

here is a copy of the connection string code:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TheYogaDen;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="TheYogaDenEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.DAL.TheYogaDenModel.csdl|res://*/App_Code.DAL.TheYogaDenModel.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.DAL.TheYogaDenModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=TheYogaDen;user id=YogaDBUser;password=Yoga!@#$;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I am able to connect to the database in the VS server explorer using that connection.  However when I go to the ASP.net web configuration tool and try to test my provider it tells me there is nothing configured.  I run the aspnet_regsql and configure the database for connection and the error still persists.

Any ideas?

Comment: please visit following link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this has happened... but I have found a solution, or rather a work around.

I went and tested another project I was working on and the connections worked fine.  So I copied the webconfig file, made a few changes to the login credentials.

not the best solution but it works.

Answer (score 0):

go to SQL Server Configuration Manager and check the state, turn on all.

Comment: all are running ... all database connections that don't require the defaultConnection are working fine.  My tables populate correctly using my Entity connection.

Comment: check the framework, version of SQL Server and Visual Studio, they must be same. put the connection in local mode.

Answer (score 0):

check in services > SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) start this service

Comment: as mentioned previously..... all services are running. I could connect using the custom connection string but not the default.